# Enumerate possible result of N choices K times

Tags: python

I'm trying to find an efficient way to enumerate all the possible outcomes of choosing from N options (with replacement) K times.

For example:

```
func(N=2, K=3) => [[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,1],[0,1,1]]

func(N=3, K=2) => [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[2,1],[1,2]]
```

What is a general way to do this in Python?

Comment: `itertools.product(range(N), repeat=K)`.

Comment: Are ;you sure you don't want `[0,1,1]` too in your first example? If you do, then `itertools.product()` is the answer. But if you don't, I can't guess what you want.

Comment: Yeah, that was an oversight, thanks.

Comment: Cool - except you repaired it not by adding `[0,1,1]`, but by including a second instance of `[0,1,0]` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the example that does what you want, except that elements were sorted

```py
import itertools

def func(N, K):
    return list(itertools.product(range(N), repeat=K))


print(func(N=2, K=3))
# => [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]

print(func(N=3, K=2))
# => [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```